# Mind Control with Nanomachines and/or Deep Brain Stimulation

Tags: hard-science, nanotechnology, brain

Imagine a technology that could be used to induce specific hallucinations in the form of dreams. Also, the same technology could be used to control someone like a puppet for short (or long) periods of time. I'm thinking nano-machines or deep brain stimulation machine. Is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing how this is not even remotely possible today, the answer would be based entirely on imagined technologies. Your question is a little broad, and asking how "likely" it is for humanity to invent mind-control nano-robots is not really what world-building is about. Maybe ask your question in a slightly different way? What is it that you really want confirmation on, seeing how in your universe you can invent any tech you wish?

Comment: I will clarify. What I'm asking about are some examples of imagined technology where this is possible, ideally extrapolated from current technologies, just a fictitious situation that sounds plausible.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd call this opinion-based, but this is incredibly broad.  You haven't even picked a single technology.  What do you want to know?  What do you know about your world or story?  Does this seem possible?  Sure.  When?  No idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently watched a [TED Talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/greg_gage_how_to_control_someone_else_s_arm_with_your_brain?language=en)   about neuroscience and they had a really nice experient. They've put electrodes on the girl's arm and the guy's arm and then the stimulous the girl's brain used to move her arm moved the guy's arm also. I believe with a human-to-human interface it would be possible. You would need to map the brain signals and create a interface to read the master's command and one to receive in the "slave".
I believe there could be a tech to control a person's body and not the talk or other behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

When I took a Hallucinogenic Mushroom in Amsterdam, I noticed I was very subjective to thoughts. I asked if I was high and I was answered that I was "high as mushroom soup". I then imagined my face like a bowl of mushroom soup. I could smell my face. I imagined that with every movement, the floating pieces of mushrooms (being my eyes, my nose, my mouth) kinda stirred and that made me even more amused.

Since then, mushroom soup makes me giggle.

I imagine there could be a substance that's even more powerful in stamping impressions on your mind and under that, you could believe things that are injected into your mind while tripping.

Also, look into Burundanga (Scopolamine). People on it look normal, act normal, but they will actually do WHATEVER THEY ARE TOLD TO DO!

Plus, Truth serum is a real thing.

Also, look into specific parasites: Toxoplasmosis is something cats release into poo, makes rats love cats and run to them - that's a behavior caused by a chemical, no need for additional thought injection. 
Some similar fungi exist. Yeast infection (candida) makes people want to eat sugar. Some fungi makes ants want to climb on top of grass blades so that they can be eaten by cows and then the fungi lives in the cow, is released in the poop, eaten by ants, etc..

I am saying: very similar chemicals exist and only need a little nudge in the right direction to make into pharmacy-grade, highly effective mind control substances. 
I wouldn't be surprised if our friends in the CIA/NSA/whatever have already capitalized on such drugs - it's just that we don't know about them.